# Calculating the total time of records with partially overlapping StartTime and EndTime values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working to aggregate some data about fueling stations from an SQL database into easy-to-understand KPIs for visualization in Grafana.

A key one is the down-time of a station in a given time-period. Down-time is considered 'when no fueling is possible at the station'. The components affecting this are the Pump and the Dispensers (usually two for a station).

Records in the FaultsAndWarnings  table have a Station, VarName, StartTime and EndTime as relevant variables. Between the start and and end-time the component is considered 'in fault' (inoperable).

I can calculate the time each individual component is 'in fault' by querying the table like below.

```
  DECLARE @__timeFrom datetime = $__timeFrom();
  DECLARE @__timeTo datetime = $__timeTo(); 
  DECLARE @__duration float = datediff(second, @__timeFrom, @__timeTo); 

    with cte as (
      select [VarName], [Station],
             (case when EndTime < @__timeTo
                   then EndTime
                   else @__timeTo
              end) as endtime,
             (case when StartTime > @__timeFrom
                   then StartTime
                   else @__timeFrom
              end) as starttime
      from [dbo].[FaultsAndWarnings]
      where VarName = 'Pump' 
      OR VarName = 'Dispenser1' 
      OR VarName = 'Dispenser2' 
      AND EndTime > @__timeFrom AND StartTime < @__timeTo 
     )

select 
    (sum(case when VarName = 'Pump' then datediff(second, StartTime, endtime) end) / @__duration) * 100 AS Pump
    (sum(case when VarName = 'Dispenser1' then datediff(second, StartTime, endtime) end) / @__duration) * 100 AS Dispenser1
    (sum(case when VarName = 'Dispenser2' then datediff(second, StartTime, endtime) end) / @__duration) * 100 AS Dispenser2
    SUBSTRING (Station, 16, 30)
from cte
group by Station;
```

(adjusted for easier reading. The actual VarNames are slightly convoluted PLC tags)

The result gives me the percentage of time of the given time-range that each component was faulty.
The '$__timeFrom()' variables are Grafana time-range inputs.

But now I want to aggregate one step further, and things get tricky.
Because what we want to see is:

- Percentage of time the station was down for 100%
- Percentage of time the station was down for 50%

100% down is: Either the Pump is down OR Dispenser 1 AND Dispenser 2 are down 
50% down is: Dispenser 1 OR Dispenser 2 is down AND Pump is NOT down

And this is where my paltry SQL skills start to falter.

It feels like I want to do the following (for calculating 100% downtime):

1. Make new intermediate table with records that fall within the time-range AND where is Pump OR where Dispenser1 and Dispenser2 overlap.

   Example:
   Pump down from StartTime 14:00 to EndTime 1800 
   Dispenser1 AND Dispenser2 down from StartTime 16:00 to 19:00 
   => Add record StationDown with StartTime 14:00 and EndTime 19:00
2. Aggregate the overlapped 100%-down-results in the same way as I already do with the individual component results.

I'm having trouble comparing records against other records though, in a way that allows me to create the new overlap-records.
Anyone have experience with this kind of trickery?

Answer (score 1):

You have a finite number of outage combinations for two pumps.  `S = start` and `E = end`.

```
[Pump 1]               S...........E  (no overlap)
[Pump 2]  S.......E

[Pump 1]      S...........E           (some overlap)
[Pump 2]  S.......E

[Pump 1]      S...........E           (complete overlap)
[Pump 2]        S.......E

[Pump 1]      S...........E           (complete overlap)
[Pump 2]    S...............E

[Pump 1]      S...........E           (some overlap)
[Pump 2]              S.......E

[Pump 1]      S......E               (no overlap)
[Pump 2]                  S.......E
```

You can measure the overlap for each use case with a single `case` statement.  You don't need to worry about the `no overlap` cases.  You'll have to test the code and see how it behaves when there are multiple outages for a single pump...

```
select overlap = 
  case
    when S1 >  S2 and E1 >  E2 then datediff(min, S1, E2)
    when S1 <= S2 and E1 >= E2 then datediff(min, S2, E2)
    when S2 <= S1 and E2 >= E1 then datediff(min, S1, E1)
    when S1 <  S2 and E1 <  E2 then datedif(min, S2, E1)
    else 0
  end
```

Comment: An interesting angle! Given that multiple outages within a time-range are very probable, and I then also need to account for overlap with Pump outage, it'll take a bit more fiddling, but you've given me a push in a direction. Thanks!